# How to update a Textual TUI within a function call?

Tags: python, tui

I'm using the [Textual](https://textual.textualize.io/) framework for a simple TUI.
The task is to display the results of ChatGPT-prompts as they are streamed.
Problem is: I cannot figure out, how to update the app, so that it shows the streamed results.
Here is a minimal example. I expect the `Counter` label to display the numbers from 0 to 9 very quickly. The result is, that I only get the number 9 after waiting for a second.

```py
import time

from textual.app import App
from textual.widgets import Header, Label
from textual.reactive import reactive


def randomgen():
    for i in range(10):
        time.sleep(0.1)
        yield str(i)


class Counter(Label):
    countervalue = reactive("Press Enter to start")

    def watch_countervalue(self, countervalue):
        self.update(countervalue)


class Minimal(App):
    def compose(self):
        yield Header()
        yield Counter(id="counter")

    def on_key(self, event):
        if event.key == "enter":
            for i in randomgen():
                self.query_one("#counter").countervalue = i  # pyright: ignore


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Minimal()
    app.run()
```

Comment: Like almost every user interface framework, nothing gets updated in real time as you make the change.  All that does is send a message requesting a change.  The display won't be updated until your handler finishes and the app gets back to the main loop to dispatch the messages..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are updating `countervalue` correctly, but there are other issues with your code that are preventing it from working.

The first is that you are using `time.sleep` which is a blocking call. Blocking calls will prevent asyncio doing anything else. You can replace `time.sleep` with `await asyncio.sleep`.

```py
import asyncio

from textual.app import App
from textual.widgets import Header, Label
from textual.reactive import reactive


def randomgen():
    for i in range(10):
        yield str(i)


class Counter(Label):
    countervalue = reactive("Press Enter to start")

    def watch_countervalue(self, countervalue):
        self.update(countervalue)


class Minimal(App):
    def compose(self):
        yield Header()
        yield Counter(id="counter")

    async def on_key(self, event):
        if event.key == "enter":
            for i in randomgen():
                self.query_one("#counter").countervalue = i  # pyright: ignore
                await asyncio.sleep(0.1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Minimal()
    app.run()
```

This works in the way I think you intended it to. Although you should avoid doing work that takes a while in message handlers, as your app won't be able to process messages until it completes.

It is better to have long running tasks in a [worker](https://textual.textualize.io/guide/workers/). Here's an example:

```py
import asyncio

from textual.app import App
from textual import work
from textual.widgets import Header, Label
from textual.reactive import reactive


class Counter(Label):
    countervalue = reactive("Press Enter to start")

    def watch_countervalue(self, countervalue):
        self.update(countervalue)


class Minimal(App):
    def compose(self):
        yield Header()
        yield Counter(id="counter")

    @work
    async def run_counter(self) -> None:
        for i in range(10):
            self.query_one("#counter", Counter).countervalue = str(i)
            await asyncio.sleep(0.1)

    async def on_key(self, event):
        if event.key == "enter":
            self.run_counter()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Minimal()
    app.run()
```

You could also implement this with [`set_interval`](https://textual.textualize.io/api/message_pump/#textual.message_pump.MessagePump.set_interval).

Comment: Thank you very much! I did not know about the blocking call. In the meantime, I solved it with a Thread, but this solution is much better! Here is the result, if you want to try:
https://github.com/Dronakurl/storytime